# What's the difference navigation drawer activitiy and empty activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, navigation-drawer

I watched some videos for navigation drawer in android studio .. some people started from an empty activity and other used Navigation Drawer Activity from the Starter ..

So what's the difference ?

And what activity i have to implement ?

(my first activity is splash screen and all others activity will be added as new activity, btw I'm doing a football application so advice me <3)

Comment: Try some research before posting question . [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer). And these Activity type are templates provided by `IDE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio provides you some templates as starting point with boilerplate code to get you started quickly on your project.

If you select DrawerActivity, It will create one of the templates, you can use which has all the boilerplate implementation for the Drawer Menu.

On the other hand, if you select EmptyActivity, It will just an create an activity with nothing in it (mostly blank or HelloWorld TextView in it, depending on studio versions).

By the way, you can always create an EmptyActivity and add things gradually like drawermenu etc in it if you prefer this way.

Comment: okay but i have to use fragments to handle click events in menu ! it is implemented ? or i have to implement it manually ( I'm talking about DrawerActivity )

Comment: I think click events will be there. You just have to provide fragment targets for those events. (see method onNavigationItemSelected()). If this solves your problem, please mark answer as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Empty activity** : It has just the white screen and nothing else.

**NavigationDrawer activity** : Empty screen integrated with Navigation Drawer